# Bean not getting autowired using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I am fairly new to Annotation Driven Spring which got introduced after Spring 2.5. I have been fairly comfortable with the XML based configuration and I have never had any problems getting beans to AutoWire using XMl approach of loading the Spring Container. Things were so cool in the XML world but then I turned to the Annotation Ville and now I have a quick question for people here: **Why would my beans won't autowire?** here are the classes that I have created:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.myspringapp.MyBean;
import com.myspringapp.MySpringAppConfig;

public class TestConfig {

@Autowired
private static MyBean myBean;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MySpringAppConfig.class);
    System.out.println(myBean.getString());
}

}
```

The above is the standard java class which invokes AnnotationConfigApplicationContext class. I was under the impression that once the "MySpringAppConfig" class is loaded I would have reference to the myBean aurowired property and hence would be able to call getString method on it. However, I am always getting null and hence NullPointerException.

```
package com.myspringapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyBean {

    public String getString() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Above is the component MyBean which is fairly simple to understand and below is the Configuration class:

```
package com.myspringapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MySpringAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am able to get the reference to bean if I use (MyBean)ctx.getBean("myBean"); but I dont want to use getBean method.

Comment: `@Autowire` can Autowire Spring managed Beans in Spring managed Beans. But `TestConfig` is not managed by Spring!

Comment: so what you mean to say here is I make this PSVM class as a JUnit Test Class and have RunWith ( SpringJUnit....) class? Will that be Managed by Spring?

Comment: Peter I was able to run this class as a Test class and the JUnit passed which means the myBean property did get autowired and I was able to assert the getString method. Now I would want to know what exactly difference it made when I added the following code to the class:

    @ContextConfiguration(classes=MySpringAppConfig.class)
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Answer (score 1):

The only way i know is to autowire a static field is to use a setter. But this will also not work in your case because Spring needs to process the object, but the `TestConfig` class is not processed in your code. If you want to inject dependencies into `TestConfig`, you can to define it as a bean:

```
public class MySpringAppConfig {
  @Bean
  public TestConfig testConfig() {
    return new TestConfig();
  }
  .....
```

Then get it via:

```
TestConfig tc = (TestConfig) ctx.getBean("testConfig");
```

Then Spring can inject `myBean`, by using the setter method.